# Are articles in the middle of titles considered when alphabetizing?

Tags: sort-ordering

I know that articles ("a", "an", "the") at the beginning of titles are ignored when alphabetizing those titles.  What about articles *in the middle* of a title?  For example, what is the proper order of these titles:

- "Spider-Man and the X-Men"
- "Spider-Man and X-Factor Shadowgames"

Does "the" precede "X-Factor", or is it ignored so that "X-Factor" precedes "X-Men"?

FYI, this example came up while organizing a comic book collection.  I expect the same rules apply for books, movies, and other works.  I doubt the rules for this are regional, but if it matters, I am interested in the US convention.

Comment: If, by *alphabetising*, you mean making into an initialism/acronym, then, as most issues of style, it is debateable. Some intialisms use articles, some don't.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey I think OP is asking about arranging titles in alphabetical order.

Comment: There is no single convention about alphabetization. Different styles offer different treatments of initial articles, ampersands and punctuation, abbreviations, and so on. You should adhere to the guidance provided by your editor, organization, or preferred [style manual](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/2579/16052).

Comment: It's entirely up to you.  Depends to a large degree on how sophisticated your software is.

Comment: I echo the style manual sentiment, but I also wonder if it matters that there is always "The" in front of "X-Men."

Comment: @StoneyB is correct.  I arrange the comic books themselves in alphabetical order by their series titles (and then by issue numbers).  I also wrote some custom software to catalog the collection, and it displays the series in alphabetical order as well.  In both cases, ordering by title helps when trying to locate a particular series or issue.

Comment: @HotLicks That's more true than you know.  I wrote the software I use, so it's as sophisticated as I have the desire and time to make it.  It's been a fun and educational project.  When I started, I didn't even know "library science" was a thing.  I reinvented a lot of wheels (poorly) before I learned enough of the vocabulary to find the existing solutions.  In part, this question was meant to find out if my current sorting algorithm is sophisticated enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each library has their own standards for alphabetizing words.

According to NISO, [Guidelines for Alphabetical Arrangement of Letters and Sorting of Numerals and Other Symbols](http://www.niso.org/publications/tr/tr03.pdf), there is no standard except articles at the beginning of the heading/title can be ignored if desired (section 4.6). Hardly a hard and fast rule.

Dartmouth Records Management has a great set of rules posted that they go by [here.](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~library/recmgmt/forms/FilingRules.pdf) They ignore the articles (Rule 12.B).

In the end, you should adopt your own personal library rules if you have a lot of sorting to do (either from a standard, someone else's model, or make up your own). Dartmouth's rules are thorough and useful and go well beyond the needs of a comic collector's needs.

Comment: I was taught the rule about ignoring leading articles in grade school, and I've seen it so often since that I'd assumed it was universal.  I was expecting to learn an equally definitive rule covering this niche case.  Instead, I discover that even the leading article thing isn't universal.  It's like dropping an apple and watching it fall upward.  My worldview is shattered! ;-)  Anyway, this answers my question.  I appreciate the Dartmouth suggestion.  I've already had to devise some personal rules for other cases, and I'm interested to see how they handle those cases.